# Kotlin: Find the parity outlier. We need to print the number which is different from other numbers in Array

Tags: arrays, kotlin

Question is: You are given an array (which will have a length of at least 3, but could be very large) containing integers. The array is either entirely comprised of odd integers or entirely comprised of even integers except for a single integer N. Write a method that takes the array as an argument and returns this "outlier" N.

Now my code is:

```
fun find(integers: Array<Int>): Int {
    var sumEven = 0
    var sumOdd = 0

 
  for ( i in integers){
      if(integers[i]%2==0){
          sumEven+=1
      } else{
          sumOdd+=1
      }
  }
    if (sumEven>sumOdd){
      for(i in integers){
          if(integers[i]%2!=0){
              print(integers[i])
          } 
      }
        
    } else{
        for(i in integers){
            if(integers[i]%2==0){
                print(integers[i])
            }
        }
    }
    return 0
}
```

Pardon me for using 3 loops but I want to understand why this code isn't working and where I am wrong.

Comment: `i` is not defined. And for each usage is wrong. `i` is not an index but it is the array value.

Comment: Need to brush up the basics. Got it. Thanks

Comment: Sorry, I missed your language. The definition of `i` is not necessary. However, it is true that `i` is not 0, 1, 2, 3, .... It becomes the elements of the array.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i` is not the index of the array, but each element of the array, so rather than `integers[i]`, you can use `i` directly.

Also, you are supposed to `return` the result, not print it.

Here's what your code should look like:

```
fun find(integers: Array<Int>): Int {
    var sumEven = 0
    var sumOdd = 0


    for (i in integers){
        if(i % 2==0){
            sumEven+=1
        } else{
            sumOdd+=1
        }
    }
    if (sumEven > sumOdd){
        for(i in integers){
            if(i % 2 != 0){
                return i
            }
        }

    } else{
        for(i in integers){
            if(i % 2==0){
                return i
            }
        }
    }
    error("This should never be reached")
}
```

However, using 3 loops is quite inefficient, and the code is overall not very idiomatic. Here's a faster version, doing it with at most one iteration through the array.

```
fun find(integers: Array<Int>): Int {
    val firstParity = integers[0] % 2
    val secondParity = integers[1] % 2
    val thirdParity = integers[2] % 2
    return when (firstParity) {
        secondParity -> integers.first { it % 2 != firstParity }
        thirdParity -> integers[1]
        else -> integers[0]
    }
}
```

The trick here is that we really only need to compare the parities of the first 3 numbers.

- If the first and second have the same parity, we know that the number to return does not have the same parity as the first or second number, and is in the rest of the list.
- Otherwise (i.e. first and second have different parities), and if the first and third number have the same parity, then we know that the second number is the outlier.
- Otherwise, it can only be the case that the second and third have the same parity, in which case the first is the outlier.